# Update on one Constraint, Ignore on other

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MySQL.

I have a unique constraint composite of 5 columns. My aim is to update counter if these 5 values are all same.

I have another unique key one column, if this is same, it shouldn't insert or do the update on duplicate key, mentioned above.

ck_unique -> `time`,`notes`,`lectures`,`status`
unique -> `id` not auto inc or sth, id is a varchar(20).

so if `id` exists, ignore whole insert or update.
if time, notes, lectures, status same, update counter by one.

I have tried where not exists, insert on duplicate key but no luck, if updates if id exists since I want that behavior for other ck_unique.

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` (`id`, `lectures`, `notes`, `time`, `status`, `counter`, `input`) VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `counter` = `counter`+1
```

But if id exists, it should ignore. ID is unique key.

[keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D8Dl.png)

[table_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4qOl.png)

seems I have to select the id first, if doesnt exist, insert/update dup key?

Comment: I think you will have to do this with a trigger.

Comment: *"so if id exists, ignore whole insert or update."* - that sounds like a unique constraint. For the rest of the question, it's hard to figure out what you need. Can you please be more elaborate and add table structure, attempted solution, example data etc.?

Comment: I have a counter, if time, notes, lectures, status are same, update it, this can be done with on duplicate key update. I have this id, generated, I want to ignore insert/update, if id is same, means user retriggering old key generated.

Comment: So, for the above insert, if id is '1', do nothing. If lecture, notes, time, status 1,1,1,1 update counter by 1 for ex VALUES ('2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'). If VALUES ('3', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1') now make new insert.

Comment: I am considering putting id to redis, if exists, ignore whole update, if doesnt, do the update on dup key.